# rle() function returns lengths and values. But what about the length of each of these values

Tags: r

The length of the elements the `rle` function returns is reported back, but it is accessible with code?  I know I can run the function `length` on `rle$lengths` to get to the value I want. But when you look at the product returned by `rle` you see that number displayed right in front of your eyes. The question is, is it retrievable?

```
v1 <- rep(seq(5),seq(3,7))
rle(v1)
```

gives us:

```
# Run Length Encoding
# lengths: int [1:5] 3 4 5 6 7
# values : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

the 5 in int [1:5] is the length of each of the returned elements. It's already there, is there a way to retrieve it, or do we have to recalculate it with `length`?

Comment: It was compouted by the routine that displays the result. Its not explicitly a component of the object.  You will need to use `length`.

Comment: specifically, `r <- rle(v1); length(r$lengths)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str()` returns the structure of the object passed to it so you can see which components are actually stored.  In this case, using `str()` on `rle(v)`:

```
v <- rle(v1)
str(v)
#List of 2
#$ lengths: int [1:5] 3 4 5 6 7
#$ values : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#- attr(*, "class")= chr "rle"
```

it looks like the output is a list of 2, so you'd still have to use something like `length` to retrieve it.